# Warning when installing Black Formatter

Tags: python

hello i got this warning when i installed Black formatter, does this cause any problems? if so how do i add it to the PATH?

```
WARNING: The scripts black.exe and blackd.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\bboys\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: sorry i didnt know i shouldnt use images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When something's not on path, it means that you won't be able to access the program by simply typing its name in your terminal or command line, as your machine doesn't simply know where the command/file/program exists.

You have to make your system aware of the particular program's existence in order to use it anywhere. To do this, we add the program in PATH.

Go through this article to add a particular program or command in PATH: https://windowsloop.com/how-to-add-to-windows-path/

Comment: Hello thanks for answering me, the formatter works wonderfully now!